# Parenthesis in a perl function call

Tags: perl

AFAIK, parenthesis in perl are for:

- setting evaluation precedence in expressions
- making a list

so,

```
my $r = ($x+$y) * $z;
my(@l) = (1,2,3);
```

What is a meaning of a parenthesis in a function call? I didn't find any, the sub will get a simple list of its arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

sub xxx { say Dumper \@_ }

xxx( 1,  2, 3  );
xxx( 1, (2, 3) );
xxx  1, (2, 3)  ;
xxx  1,  2, 3;
```

right?

Asking because the `perl -MO=Deparse` didn't remove the parenthesis from the function calls.

so for the next short script

```
use Moose;
has 'arg' => (is=>'rw', isa=>'Str');
```

returns

```
has('arg', ('is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str'));
```

and not the simple

```
has('arg', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str');
```

Is here any difference?

Comment: Just a comment: When playing with parentheses, use `Deparse,-p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, an exception to "they're all the same" would be something like this:

```
xxx (1,2), 3;
```

The difference between the following:

```
has('arg', ('is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str'));
has('arg', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str');
```

is that the former builds one list, then builds a second list, pushing the first list onto it. The latter builds everything as a single list. You can see the difference using B::Concise; they compile to slightly different op trees. The former example will run ever so slightly slower, but there's little difference in it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

cmpthese(-5, {
  once   => q[  my @x = (foo => (bar => 1, baz => 2))  ],
  twice  => q[  my @x = (foo =>  bar => 1, baz => 2 )  ],
});

__END__
       Rate twice  once
twice 216835/s    --   -1%
once  218228/s    1%    --
```

Comment: That benchmark is probably not meaningful. The difference is so small that it's likely just statistical fluctuation. Of course there is no way to know without seeing the raw data set. On the other hand a slight slowdown is what I would expect.

Comment: I've run that benchmark several times, and `once` is consistently faster, though never by more than about 1%. (Often less than 0.5% difference.)

Answer (score 2):

When the parens are not removed by deparsing, this is because they can be used to determine precedence. The snippets `has('arg', 'is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str')` and `has('arg', ('is', 'rw', 'isa', 'Str'))` produce different Opcodes (although in this case the difference could be removed safely).

Parens do not create lists. “Lists” in Perl are not distinct data structures. They are just a more accessible description of a stack segment. If anything would create a list, then it would be the comma operator `,` in list context. (But it doesn't as there are no lists).

If the subroutine you are calling is known at parse time, then the parens from a function invocation are optional, i.e. the syntax is either `any_function(@args)` or `known_function @args`. Known functions can also use *prototypes* to change how the arguments are parsed (regardless of whether parens where used). For known functions it is not relevant whether the deparsed call uses parens, or not: both produce the same Opcodes.